# how to edit /manifast.xml file and mainpage.dox to finish package creation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
i am a beginner and i am working on ubuntu 10.04 with ros electric version
I want to make a package name as sag then it shows me
current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable
Please edit sag/manifest.xml and mainpage.dox to finish creating your package

please help me ..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42313/how-to-edit-/manifast.xml-file-and-mainpage.dox-to-finish-package-creation/) by [sagar](https://answers.ros.org/users/3085/sagar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to [configure your ROS environment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) correctly, then follow the [tutorial for creating a package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1